# Visual C# - Program Will Not Run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I made a program with Visual Studio 2010. It required .NET Framework 4.0 to run, and the machine it needs to run on is not connected to the internet, so I found the redistributable online on my own machine and copied it over.

I installed the software on the machine (it's a very simple program, I just made up an installer to do the .NET installation as well as putting the .exe file of my program into Program Files) but any time I try to run it, I get a Windows Error Report message saying the program failed to run.

Are there any suggestions as to where I could look for the cause of this issue?

(If it matters, the machine I'm trying to run it on is running Windows XP while I am running Windows 7. I don't think this is a compatibility issue though...)

Comment: Provide some code/hints or post at http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Check if the Windows 7 machine 64bit while the XP machine 32bit.

Comment: how do I check if I'm compiling for x64? I am on a 64 bit machine, but I wasn't aware that the compiler would be set as 64-bit by default.

Comment: Check the Project > Properties. Make sure the compilation is set to "Any CPU" or 32 bit one.

Comment: This isn't the problem. I just checked and the program has been set to compile for x86. I'll try it for Any CPU, but it doesn't seem like that will be the problem. Thanks, though.

Comment: Do you have any more error information? Like a stacktrace or memory dump?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're having is with error handling.  There is probably an environmental issue such as a missing folder, registry setting, or some other configuration.  That would explain why it works on your dev machine and not the other (a common occurrence.)  Your app is throwing an unhandled exception and crashing.

There may be information on the error in the Application log, including a stacktrace you can use to diagnose the issue.  Once you have determined the problem, you will also want to ensure that you have sufficient exception handling so you can raise friendly error messages and prevent your app from crashing.

Comment: Agreed.  It won't be in the event log, write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  Display e.ExceptionObject.ToString().

Comment: How do I write that though? I'm a bit new to C#.

Comment: @rar type 'System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=' in VS and let the editor create a new handler for you.  Then just `MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject)` [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) for more info.

Comment: 'MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject)'

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: 'MessageBox.Show(ToString(e.ExceptionObject));' no overload method for 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 1):

Could possibly be that you built a 64 bit app and you're trying to run it on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: This was many years ago now, but yeah that's what I'm thinking it was. I don't recall most of the details, but I was new to programming at the time, so this could've easily flown over my head.